# How do I replicate v-models :value with :value?

Tags: vue.js, input, v-model

I get different behavior between using `@input` and `v-model`, and  `@input` and `:value`.

What is v-model doing different with :value that I dont get with only using :value?

I created an [example at jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7zjnmd2/12/) that show the difference: that the top input field would allow only numbers to be typed into the input, while the bottom will allow everything to be typed in.

What do I need to do to get the same functionality by using only `@input` and `:value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding an ref to the input and updating input value through it. Check here. https://jsfiddle.net/RiddhiParekh/nzfr0xy3/

Template =>

```
    <div id="app">
  <div>
    <input @input="mask1" 
           v-model="message1" 
           type="text" 
           placeholder="Only numbers are allowed">
    <p>Message1 is: {{ message1 }}</p>
    <hr/>
    <input @input="mask2" 
           :value="message2"
           type="text"
           ref="myInput"
           placeholder="Try numbers">
    <p>Message2 is: {{ message2 }}</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Script =>

```
 new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   message1: "",
   message2: ""
  },
  methods: {
    mask1(input){
        const validCharsForNumberFields = /[0-9]*(,|\.)?[0-9]*/gm
      this.message1 = input.target.value.match(validCharsForNumberFields)[0]
        },
    mask2(input){
      const validCharsForNumberFields = /[0-9]*(,|\.)?[0-9]*/gm
      console.log(input)
      this.$refs.myInput.value = input.target.value.match(validCharsForNumberFields)[0]
      this.message2 = this.$refs.myInput.value
    },

  }
})
```